# Количество повторений в массиве через reduce

Tags: javascript

Уже видел ответы на вопрос подсчёта повторений в массиве, но не понятно, что конкретно делает 2строка  **acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1;**

```
 var result = [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 4, 5].reduce(function(acc, el) {
      acc[el] = (acc[el] || 0) + 1;
      return acc;
    }, {});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это `(acc[el] || 0)` выражение в скобках вернёт `acc[el]`, если оно эквивалентно `true`, или 0 в ином случае.

Часто используется в `js` для присвоения значения по-умолчанию.  (`var obj = o || {}` - если `o` равен `undefined`, `null`, `false` и тд, то в переменную `obj` пойдёт `{}` пустой объект).

Или вот:

```
alert(null || undefined || false || '' || 0 || 4 || 'bar'); // alerts '4'
```

Первый параметр, который эквивалентен логическому `true`, и будет выведен.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation) есть несколько хороших ответов на эту тему.

Comment: это я понимаю, что она возвращет если true, но почему записано именно в таком виде, а не в if(acc[el] || 0){acc[el]+=1}

Comment: @Kocta потому что в программировании есть такие понятия, как `statement` (инструкция) и `expression` (выражение). Инструкция - фрагмент кода, влияющий на выполнение программы. Пример тому - `if statement`. В зависимости от переданного аргумента выполняется либо блок `if`, либо блок `else` (если таковой имеется). `acc[el] || 0` же, в свою очередь, выражение. Выражение - фрагмент кода, результатом которого является величина. `2 + 3`, например, тоже выражение, и результат его выполнения будет `5`. Вы можете использовать `if` вместо `||`, но такая конструкция иногда может быть громоздкой.

Comment: как в нашем случае acc[el] может быть не true? и если он всегда true то зачем нам || 0? можем ли мы записать выражение как acc[el]+=1, т.е каждый раз когда значение el повторяется мы добаляем +1 к значению которое у нас в объекте

Comment: @Kocta а вы понимаете принцип того, как работает этот метод подсчета повторений? Для начала в метод `reduce` вы передаёте аккумулятор - пустой объект (`{}`). Потом для каждого элемента мы пробуем получить в этом объекте значение по ключу `el`. Если до этого в массиве не встречалась, скажем, 4, то по этому ключу мы получим `undefined`. В таком случае наше выражение вернет нам не `undefined + 1`, а `0 + 1`, что и будет записано в объект по этому ключу (4 в данном случае).

Comment: Кстати, если вы захотите использовать данный метод для подсчета повторений строк (пустая строка эквивалентна `false` в булевом контексте) (или подсчета повторений в массиве, в котором хранятся `0`, `null` итд), то код будет работать неверно. Скажем, если в массиве один или больше `0`, то этот метод всегда будет показывать, что их 1, ибо будет каждый раз обнуляться, встретив очередной `0`. Так что если вы хотите отслеживать и эти случаи, то вместо `||`-выражения сделайте проверку только на `undefined`: `if (acc[el] == undefined) { acc[el] = 0 } acc[el] += 1`

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас более менее понял, до этого не понимал что по ключу `undefined` получаем